# What contributes to my iPhone iCloud backup size?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

Settings lists my phone's iCloud "Backup Size" as 2.2 GB (excluding other phones and general "Documents & Data") though all of its apps turned "on" for backup below don't even approach 0.5 GB when summed. What else is contributing to this unexpectedly large number, and how can I reduce them?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12519?viewlocale=en_US), this is what is backed up:

- Purchased music, movies, TV shows, apps, and books
- Photos and videos in your Camera Roll
- Device settings
- App data
- Home screen and app organization
- iMessage, text (SMS), and MMS messages
- Ringtones
- Visual Voicemail

Things like purchased content, Messages.app, ringtones, and voicemails are not actually explicitly listed in the backup screens for you to see how much space will be used. This would account for the difference.